# Regarding performance of select: post delete or truncate the table?

Tags: mysql, performance

Do the performance of  select query decreases if I remove the data from a table using delete ?Is there any performance difference if I use truncate to clear the entire table in comparison with delete the selected rows.

Comment: If there are no foreign keys that reference the table, then this table is dropped/recreated instantly. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html

```
Truncate operations drop and re-create the table, which is much faster than deleting rows one by one, particularly for large tables.
```

also: http://www.softstuff-consulting.com/kbase/showkb.asp?id=15